# On likelihood functions and characteristic functions

Tags: probability, expected-value, likelihood, independence, characteristic-function

Let me preface this by saying that if someone manages to provide a solution to my problem, I will forever be indebted to them, as this problem has driven me crazy. Let us first assume that the discrete variables $S_1,S_2,...,S_n$ are independent and can be explained by an information matrix, say $n\times k$ matrix $X=[x_0,x_1,...,x_{n-1}]$, where $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$. That would imply that their log-likelihood function can be expressed by
\begin{eqnarray}
L(\mathbf{S_n};\theta)=\log P\left[S_1=s_1,...,S_n=s_n\mid X\right]&=&\log\prod_{t=1}^{n}P\left[S_t=s_t\mid X\right]\\
&=&\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n}\log P\left[S_t=s_t\mid X\right]
\end{eqnarray}
Now let us assume that a test statistic, say $S_{n,\text{independent}}$ is based on the above log-likelihood function. Therefore, the characteristic function of the statistic $S_{n,\text{independent}}$ w.r.t $X$ can be written as
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi_{S_{n,\text{independent}}}(u)&=&\mathbb{E}_{X}\left[\exp{\left(iuS_{n,\text{independent}}\right)}\right]\\
&=&\mathbb{E}_{X}\left[\exp{\left(iu\left\{\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n}\log P\left[S_t=s_t\mid X\right]\right\}\right)}\right]\\
&=&\mathbb{E}_{X}\left[\prod\limits_{t=1}^{n}\exp{\left(iu\left\{\log P\left[S_t=s_t\mid X\right]\right\}\right)}\right]\\
\end{eqnarray}
and due to independence of $S_1,...,S_n$

\begin{equation}
\phi_{S_{n,\text{independent}}}(u)=\prod\limits_{t=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}_{X}\left[\exp{\left(iu\left\{\log P\left[S_t=s_t\mid X\right]\right\}\right)}\right]
\end{equation}

Dependent case:

Now consider an identical problem to the one before, where now $S_1,...,S_n$ are dependent. Then from given the chain rule in probability, the log-likelihood function will change to 
\begin{eqnarray}
L(\mathbf{S_n};\theta)=\log P\left[S_1=s_1,...,S_n=s_n\mid X\right]\\
=\log\prod_{t=1}^{n}P\left[S_t=s_t\mid S_1=s_1,...,S_{t-1}=s_{t-1},X\right]\\
=\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n}\log P\left[S_t=s_t\mid S_1=s_1,...,S_{t-1}=s_{t-1} ,X\right]
\end{eqnarray}
where now
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi_{S_{n,\text{dependent}}}(u)&=&\mathbb{E}_{X}\left[\exp{\left(iuS_{n,\text{dependent}}\right)}\right]\\
&=&\mathbb{E}_{X}\left[\exp{\left(iu\left\{\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n}\log P\left[S_t=s_t\mid S_1=s_1,...,S_{t-1}=s_{t-1}, X\right]\right\}\right)}\right]\\
&=&\mathbb{E}_{X}\left[\prod\limits_{t=1}^{n}\exp{\left(iu\left\{\log P\left[S_t=s_t\mid X\right]\right\}\right)}\right]\\
\end{eqnarray}.
Am I correct that since $S_1,...S_n$ are no longer independent, such decomposition does not exist?
\begin{equation}
\phi_{S_{n,\text{dependent}}}(u)\neq\prod\limits_{t=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}_{X}\left[\exp{\left(iu\left\{\log P\left[S_t=s_t\mid S_1=s_1,...,S_{t-1}=s_{t-1},X\right]\right\}\right)}\right]
\end{equation}
Or could we decompose as above due to conditional independence?